# PHP calling with Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a jquery file in which i have the following code:

```
var QUESTIONS = ["Q11", "Q22", "Q33", "Q44", "Q55"];
var ANSWERS = [["Si", "No"], ["Si", "No"], ["Si", "No"], ["Si", "No"], ["Si", "No"]];
```

Now i want to load the questions and answers from the PHP.

Comment: Which PHP? Don't see any.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: You should give us a problem in order to us to give you a solution.

Comment: i agree with @HerrSerker if you store you QA using Js, keep using js i don't see any reason to change...

Comment: Ajax+Json are your friends.

Comment: i have to gett he values from the database

Answer (score 2):

**Trolling ahead!**

If you want to load javascript into the PHP Userspace, you will need to lex and parse it, then read it into your own PHP userspace.

1. Create a javascript lexer to read the content of the file
2. From the token list, create a parser that will validate and construct and complex expression tree
3. Then you can analyse the expression tree and extract the different values into model classes you will have created.

Or, you could simply, just copy the content over to PHP and use it normally!

Answer (score 1):

You have three choices here.

### Inline PHP

In the `.PHP` file that generates your web-page, directly write the text for your JavaScript arrays as if they were HTML or plain-text.

### AJAX

Use an `XMLHttpRequest` object to call a separate a `.PHP` page that returns an XML response containing your entries.  (You could also have it return JSON instead of XML.)

### JSON-P

Have your PHP return JSON to a `<script>` tag, which gets automatically parsed and executed on the client.  (usually as a single global variable.)

Answer (score 0):

dataServer.php

```
$response = array();
$response['questions'] = array("Q11", "Q22", "Q33", "Q44", "Q55");
$response['answers'] = array(array("Si", "No"), array("Si", "No"), array("Si", "No"), array("Si", "No"), array("Si", "No"));
print json_encode($response);
```

dataClient.js

```
$.ajax({
    url: "dataServer.php",
    dataType: "json",
    type: "GET",
    success: function(data, stat, xhr) {
        alert(data.questions.toSource());
        alert(data.answers.toSource());
    }
});
```

Comment: what if i have this 

$data = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
 $data[] = $row; 
  }
print json_encode($response);

Comment: I have tried your but it didnt show any result

Comment: I fixed the code, now it should work. At least works on my machine.